# How to set up Eclipse + StatET + Rcpp on ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, r, rcpp

I have used the following manual and setup eclipse for rcpp.

http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170

I can build package for R, but I get the following error when I want to debug it:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error: could not find function "errorOccured"
Execution halted
```

I use eclipse in ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check the Shared option in the Cross G++ Linker>Shared Library Settings.
After that -fPic must be enabled (Other flags).

The problem is that I can build it without error but still I can not run it in the eclipse!
It create libMyCppPackage and want to run MyCppPackage!

```
  The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist
  /media/EXt4ENC/Rcpp/MyCppPackage/Debug/MyCppPackage not found
```

abd this link could not help:
http://hyperspec.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/ides/